# Produce multiple documents using a loop in LaTex

Tags: r, loops

I want to produce multiple documents in LaTeX. There is a list of values for every document that should be created, in the example it´s `\mylist`. My first approach was to use the `\foreach` function to define variables and write my document with place holders in the loop body. Of course this is not a good solution but it shows what I want to do.

I am looking for an approach to set the variables in the preamble or something similar. The goal is to run the code and get several PDF-files, one for every loop run, with a table of contents etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\newcommand{\mylist}{A/first/red, B/second/green}

\begin{document}

\foreach \i / \j / \k in \mylist {
    \clearpage

    \section{The letter \i}

    The letter \i ~is the \j ~letter of the alphabet. 

    \section{The coulor of the letter \i}

    It is represented by the coulor \k.

    \includegraphics{./\k.png}

    \clearpage
    }

\end{document}
```

If it´s not possible to get multiple PDF-files, maybe there is a way to produce one as a chain of documents. This would also help of course.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Inspired by the comment of Roland Smith I used R to loop over tex code and produce multiple PDF documents. Still I am interested in a pure tex code solution.

In R there is also the `knitr` package or the `sweave` function to connect R and tex but I used the tools package because it works reverse to them. While `knitr` and `sweave` allow to insert R code into tex code, the tools package can be used to insert tex code in R code. Here is my approach:

(To run the code you need the R script, a tex file called `empty.tex` and two *.png ("red" and "green") in one folder.)

```
## set working directory to source file location
this.dir <- dirname(parent.frame(2)$ofile)
setwd(this.dir)

require(tools)

## data frame with values used in the documents
## each row is for one document ( == one lopp run)

values <- data.frame(letter = c("A", "B"),
                     position = c("first", "second"),
                     color = c("red", "green"),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## generating Textcode
## use "\\" instead of "\" in the tex code since R quotes "\\" as "\"
## write "\n" after every line of tex code for better legibility
## "\n" means newline in R

## preamble code which is constant for all documents

preamble.const <- paste0("\\documentclass{article}", "\n",
                         "\\usepackage{graphicx}", "\n")

## define the document environment commands
begin <- "\\begin{document} \n"
end   <- "\\end{document} \n"

for (i in 1:nrow(values)) {

  ## set the variables for the current document
  ## as the variable part of the preamble

  preamble.var <- paste0(
    "\\newcommand{\\letter}{", values$letter[i], "}", "\n",
    "\\newcommand{\\position}{", values$position[i], "}", "\n",
    "\\newcommand{\\coulor}{", values$color[i], "}", "\n")

  ## the document body

  body <- paste0(
    "\\section{The letter \\letter}",
    "\n", "\n",
    "The letter \\letter ~is the \\position ~letter of the alphabet.",
    "\n", "\n",
    "\\section{The coulor of the letter \\letter}",
    "\n", "\n",
    "It is represented by the coulor \\coulor.",
    "\n", "\n",
    "\\includegraphics{./\\coulor.png}",
    "\n"
  )

  ## join to comlete Tex code

  tex_code <- paste0(
    preamble.const,
    preamble.var,
    "\n", ## blank line after preamble
    begin,
    "\n", ## blank line after \begin{document}
    body,
    "\n", ## blank line before \begin{document}
    end
  )

  ## the name of the emerging document (name.pdf)
  name <- paste0("letter_", values$letter[i])

  ## generate the temporary *.tex file used in this loop run 
  file.copy(
    from = paste0(getwd(), "/empty.tex"),
    to = paste0(getwd(), "/",name , ".tex") )


  ## set the path of the *.tex file to be used
  tex.path <- paste0(getwd(), "/",name , ".tex")

  ## write code to *.tex file
  cat(tex_code, file = tex.path)

  ## compile *.tex file
  texi2pdf(tex.path, clean = TRUE)

  ## delete the temporary *.tex file used in this loop run
  file.remove(paste0(getwd(), "/",name , ".tex") )

}

## empty the empty.tex file (not really necessary, just to get the initial state) )
cat( "", file = paste0(getwd(), "/empty.tex") )
```

Comment: It would probably be easier to have a general-purpose programming language generate different TeX files and then call `pdflatex` on every one of them to generate pdf files.